# Beam SQL - SqlValidatorException: Object 'PCOLLECTION' not found

Tags: apache-beam, beam-sql

I am doing some experiments with Beam SQL. 
I get a `PCollection<Row>` from the transform `SampleSource` and pass its output to a `SqlTransform`.

```java
String sql1 = "select c1, c2, c3 from PCOLLECTION where c1 > 1";
```

The code below runs without any error.

```java
POutput it = p.apply(new SampleSource()).apply(SqlTransform.query(sql1));
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

However, when I try the following lines of code, I get a runtime error.

```java
POutput it = p.apply(new SampleSource());
it.getPipeline().apply(SqlTransform.query(sql1));
p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

The error details are

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_extensions_sql.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Object 'PCOLLECTION' not found
```

Please provide some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're applying a `SqlTransform` to a pipeline, not a `PCollection`.

You probably want to change it along these lines:

```java
// source probably returns a PCollection,
// would make sense to change 'it' to PCollection:
PCollection<...> it = p.apply(new SampleSource());

// then apply SqlTransform to the PCollection from the previous step,
// that is apply it directly to 'it':
it.apply(SqlTransform.query(sql1));

...
```

How Beam pipeline works, from high level perspective:

- create a pipeline;
- apply an IO `PTransform` that reads from some source and produces a `PColelction` of some elements that it reads from the source;
- chain-apply more `PTransforms` to the `PCollection` from the previous step to process the data (conceptually, different `PCollections` will be produced at each step);
- repeat;

`SqlTransform` is a normal `PTransform`, it is expected to be applied to a `PCollection` of elements and output another `PCollection` as a result. The query that you specify in `SqlTransform.create()` is applied to a `PCollection`. It expects the data to come from a magical `PCOLLECTION` table that represents the `PCollection` that you apply the `SqlTransform` to.

What you are doing in your example is different:

- create a pipeline;
- apply a source `PTransform` that produces a `POutput` not necessarily a `PCollection`;
- then you ignore the output if your source, but instead take the original pipeline and apply a `SqlTransform` directly to it;

So what happens is that `SqlTransform` in this case is applied to the 'root' of the pipeline, not to the `PCollection` that comes out of the source. Instead of chain of `PTransforms` applied one after another you now have two `PTransforms` applied to the root independently from each other.

One more caveat is that `SqlTransform` expects input elements to be `Rows`, because SQL as a language works only on data that is represented as rows. There are two ways to achieve this:

- manually convert the elements that are produced by the source to `Rows` by applying another `ParDo` between the source and `SqlTransform`;
- use Beam's `Schema` framework (e.g. check out `PCollection.setSchema()` method) that allows Beam SQL to automatically convert input elements into `Rows`;

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Resolved my issue.